# Pandas list comprehension over columns instead of rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, type-conversion, list-comprehension

I'm trying to convert the following loop to list comprehension:

```
# convert integer-only valued columns from type float to type int
for col in df:
    if sum(df[col]%1) == 0:
        df[col]=df[col].astype(int)
```

I can't seem to get the syntax for this to work properly. This is what I've tried so far:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame([df[col].astype(int) if sum(df[col]%1)==0 else df[col] for col in df])
```

This seems to transpose my data frame and not actually convert the types. Would someone please help me out? Also if there's a more idiomatic way to convert int-only valued columns from float to int type I'm open to a different approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df[col].astype(int) if sum(df[col]%1)==0 else df[col] for col in df], 1)
```

Or:

```
df = df.astype(df.dtypes.mask((df%1==0).all(), 'int'))
```

Comment: Glad can help you!

Comment: I couldn't tkink of passing a series to astype. Will not forget this one.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't we use `np.where` and a `dict` to map dtypes  i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'co1':[1.,2.,3.,4.],'co2':[2.5,6.5,7.5,1.3]})

df = df.astype(dict(zip(df.columns,np.where((df%1==0).all(),np.int,df.dtypes))))

   co1  co2
0  1   2.5
1  2   6.5
2  3   7.5
3  4   1.3
```